# Sync databases models openshift

Tags: python, mysql, django, synchronization, openshift

I have account in Openshift. I use Django and Mysql in this account. https://github.com/ogurchik/pullover/tree/master/wsgi/openshift.
I created models for a new table in the Mysql database. When I execute the command `python manage.py sqlall MY_APP`, it renders this log:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE `books_publisher` (

    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `city` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    `state_province` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `website` varchar(200) NOT NULL
);
```

and etc.
I think this log means what account's environment setup suitable. But when I execute command `python manage.py syncdb`, the log is:

```
Creating tables ...

Installing custom SQL ...

Installing indexes ...

Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

But the database has nothing. How do I solve this problem? I have tried google'ing but I find nothing similar.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your app is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings file.

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'books',

Comment: have you already synced the DB before, and have now changed the model?

Comment: I didn't sync database before now. This first time. How i can examine connection my app to my settings? I think problem is wrong settings.py in my root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, the reason for the problem is my inattention. Today I checked my database and I found the syncdb done. The tables I needed were created. Seems the process of syncing the database's models executes during `git push` and rebooting the Openshift cartridge.